# Fisher-Yates Shuffle. jQuery-wrapped objects. 

Tags: jquery, each, shuffle

Sorry if this question is dumb, I don't think it is because I can't find a straight answer.  I'm trying to implement the standard Fisher-Yates shuffle, but on a **jQuery-wrapped array of DOM elements.**  I.e. the usual 'swap' algorithm.

The idea was to implement shuffling a deck of cards.

My initial simple (but hacky) solution:

1) assign an index attribute to each DOM element, and at the same time create a list of indices.

```
indices = [];
deck.each(function(i){
    $(this).attr('index',i);
    indices[i] = i;        
});
```

2) shuffle the indices array,

```
for(i=0;i<indices.length;i++){
    temp = indices[i]; 
    j = Math.floor((Math.random()*i));
    indices[i]=indices[j];
    indices[j]=temp; 
}
```

and iterate through them, using something like, I dunno, say:

```
for(i=0;i<indices.length;i++){
     randomCard = $('[index='+indices[i]+']');
     //do amazing game-like things
}
```

---

**BUT...I hate this solution, it feels extremely hacky.  I'd much rather manipulate the wrapped set.**

---

SO...

Once again here's the pseudo code for the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

```
deck.each(function(i){ 
    temp = deck[i]; //except that I want deck[i] to be a **wrapped object**

    j = Math.floor((Math.random()*i));

    deck[i]=deck[j]; //and deck[j] should find a wrapped object in the 'elements' set with index j

    deck[j]=temp; //and this should perform the swap.

    alert("I can haz swapburgers!!!");  //yay.
});
```

The part I don't understand how to do is to set the value of an element in a jQuery wrapped object by its index.  Should I be passing the indices and the parent element to a swap function?  Something like

```
swap($(this).parent(),i,j);
```

If anyone can help me sort this out I'd appreciate it.  I hope all of this is clear.  Please let me know if it's confusing and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but the jQuery object is a lot like an array as is (integer-indexing, length property) so you can almost always use it that way...there's also a [jQuery `.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) method, which returns a true array. Also, there's a [jQuery `.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method, so you don't need a new attribute for that.

Comment: What does `Obviously it doesn't actually work here because swapping in jQuery is hard.` mean?

Comment: I think I actually figured it out.  I was trying to log what happened before and after the shuffle, and the console was just logging the shuffled deck every time.

Comment: What I was meant was that switching the array elements was not appearing to give me jQuery-wrapped elements when I logged them, which was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can just treat the jquery selection like a normal array, as far as swapping goes.

```
function swap(obj, index1, index2) {
    var temp = obj[index1];
    obj[index1] = obj[index2];
    obj[index2] = temp;
}
```